# External Image not shown because of parameters in URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm struggling with SSRS to get external Images shown on my report.

**Situation/Environment**

- SSRS 12
- Images are hosted on Akamai (Caching Server)

**Problem**

- If I call the image by http://server/folder/image.jpg I see the image in  Report Builder Design View, Preview and online on the server. HTML on the server:

  ```
  <img onload="this.fitproportional=true;this.pv=0;this.ph=0;" height="155" src="/Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?
  ReportSession=0vesr555hdhfqebcbzbyf4el&amp;Culture=1031&amp;CultureOverrides=False&amp;UICulture=7&amp;UICultureOverrides=False&amp;ReportStack=1&amp;
  ControlID=db6faa0405f142afa197478522ab25ae&amp;OpType=ReportImage&amp;IterationId=822ad1f6603e4ed5a7669b1863d74b1f&amp;
  StreamID=73e6746a0121466fa7e9c958c3dfb384" width="96">
  ```
- If I call the image by http://server/folder/image.jpg?downsize=100:* I see the image in Report Builder Design View **but not** in Preview and not online on the server. HTML:

  ```
  <img onload="this.fitproportional=true;this.pv=0;this.ph=0;" height="155px" src="">
  ```

**Testing**

That behavior can be tested with these examples:

- Working: http://tech.akamai.com/image-manager/img/mountain.jpeg
- Not working: http://tech.akamai.com/image-manager/img/mountain.jpeg?downsize=640:*

I have to use the downsize parameter (and others) as the images are stored in full resolution and the report gets really big if they're not resized. The list of images is dynamically loaded by a SQL-Dataset and there are tons of images so I can't resize and save them somewhere else...

I tried many URL/parameter constellation and my conclusion is: **SSRS can't/won't handle the =** (equal sign) in the image path.
All other characters seems to work without trouble only the equal sign.

Did somebody had the same problem and found a solution for handling "=" in SSRS external Image URL paths?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ASCII `%3D` rather than an equals symbol?

Comment: I tried... But even Chrome won't translate `%3D` to `=`